# Role and Attribution ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an Admin which adds several recordings. Here, I have 2 formers.

[image]

The user `Gofette` can login and see his informations... 
[image]

Now, my problem is that the user 1 which is user `Remace` cannot login ??? I think ID 1 is reserved to admin only ?

Do you know how to solve that?

Here is an idea of my code:

```
public function index()
{   

  if($has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')){
       $formers = Former::oldest()->paginate(5);
       return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));

  } else{
       $formers = Former::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);
       return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first add role for every  user & admin in database
then get role using hasRole()